# Controlling the size of ticks when manually specifying tick labels

Tags: plotting, ticks

I'm working on a plot in which I would like to manually label ticks on the y-axis. However, it seems that manually specifying the tick labels also changes the size of the ticks compared to Mathematica's default behaviour. For example:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 8 Pi}, 
    Ticks -> {Automatic, {{-1.0, "-1"}, {-0.9, ""}, {-0.8, ""}, {-0.7, 
 ""}, {-0.6, ""}, {-0.5, "-0.5"}, {-0.4, ""}, {-0.3, ""}, {-0.2, 
 ""}, {-0.1, ""}, {0.1, ""}, {0.2, ""}, {0.3, ""}, {0.4, 
 ""}, {0.5, "0.5"}, {0.6, ""}, {0.7, ""}, {0.8, ""}, {0.9, 
 ""}, {1.0, "1"}}}]
```

The problem here is that all ticks on the y-axis have the same size, whereas by default Mathematica automatically increases the size of every fifth tick, as on the x-axis of the above example.

How can I manually specify ticks, but keep the default Mathematica behaviour where every fifth tick is larger?

Edit: here's the image referred to below.

[image]

Comment: Look up `Ticks` in the documentation under “Details”. There’s a length parameter, `{1.0, “1”, len}` or `{1.0, “1”, {right, left}}`, where `right` is how far right and `left`  is how far left the tick should go.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tick specification takes, besides the label, also a length. Here is your example:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 8 Pi}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, {{-1.0, "-1", 0.02}, {-0.9, ""}, {-0.8, 
     ""}, {-0.7, ""}, {-0.6, ""}, {-0.5, "-0.5", 0.02}, {-0.4, 
     ""}, {-0.3, ""}, {-0.2, ""}, {-0.1, ""}, {0.1, ""}, {0.2, 
     ""}, {0.3, ""}, {0.4, ""}, {0.5, "0.5", 0.02}, {0.6, ""}, {0.7, 
     ""}, {0.8, ""}, {0.9, ""}, {1.0, "1", 0.02}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The additional 0.02 specification does indeed change the size of the ticks, but it seems that this also causes the ticks to be centred at y=0, i.e. half of the length of the ticks is to the left of y=0, and the other half to the right of y=0, whereas the default behaviour is for the ticks to start and y=0 and only extend towards the right of y=0. Same goes for the x-axis: ticks only extend upwards of x=0, but not below x=0. Any idea on how to change this? Edit: actually, it looks fine in the picture you've attached, but not in my Mathematica notebook (v12.0.0.0).

Comment: I've just attached an image to my initial post in which I've increased the size for the 1.0 tick to 0.05 to better illustrate the problem.

Comment: This seems to be a version problem. I have 12.3.0. There the ticks are NOT centered a zero as you can see in my picture.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. Is there any way I can fix this problem without upgrading?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Ok. If there's no solution in the next 48h that would also fix the problem in v12.0.0 I'll happily accept your answer.